# Gummi breaking on inclusion of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Gummi is refusing to compile whenever I include the line

```
\bibliography{bibliog.bib}{}
```

I've tried with and without the .bib and it doesn't seem to matter what the contents of the file are (I've even tried with empty files). In addition it doesn't matter whether there are citations in the text or not. If anyone has any suggestions that would be brilliant

After a few errors complaining about citations being undefined the only error in the output text is:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1377) in paragraph at lines 29--30
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 of galax-ies con-tain-ing black holes at their cen-tres,
(/tmp/.CompRep.tex.bbl

LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastBibItem' on page 1 undefined on input line 1.

/tmp/.CompRep.tex.bbl:16: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@empty \apjl 
                         \xdef \UL@spfactor {\the \spacefactor }
l.16 \newblock {\em \apjl}
                      , 539:L13--L16, August 2000.
/tmp/.CompRep.tex.bbl:16:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /tmp/.CompRep.tex.log.
```

Comment: The `.bib` extension is definitely to be removed. The error seems to be in a `\apjl` macro in one of the bibliography entries.

Comment: thanks a lot, had to remove those and it sorted it! They were from adsabs generated for the aastex package so didn't work well with revtex which I was using.